# с++ include выдает ошибку. Почему?

Tags: c++

Есть три файла.

my.cpp:

```
#include "my.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print_foo() {
    cout << foo << endl;
}

void print(int i) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

my.hpp:

```
extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);
```

use.cpp:

```
#include "my.hpp"

int main() {
    foo = 7;
    print_foo();
    print(99);
}
```

Ввожу в терминал(MAC OS):

```
g++ my.hpp use.cpp my.cpp
```

Компилятор выдаёт:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_foo", referenced from:
      _main in use-0e4909.o
      print_foo() in my-c4d67b.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z9print_foov)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: Вообще говоря, `my.hpp` в командной строке совершенно не нужен. А ошибка в том, что нет определения `int foo;` в одном из .cpp-файлов.

Comment: Куда тогда его девать?

Comment: Никуда - он же у вас включается в .cpp-файлы, а не компилируется отдельно...

Comment: Foo инициализируется в use.cpp

Comment: Инициализируется, но не определяется. Есть только объявление...

Comment: Foo = 7 - не определение?

Comment: Нет, это использование. `extern int foo;` говорит примерно "где-то потом я определю эту переменную, пока просто считай, что она есть". Грубая аналогия - в том же .hpp-файле у вас есть `void print(int);` - вас же не удивляет, что вы где-то должны описать **тело** этой функции? Да, еще одним решением будет в современном C++ объявить в .hpp ее как `inline int foo;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь в файл `my.cpp`:

```
int foo;
```

> Тогда зачем я его экстерном в заголовочном объявлял?

Он там означает "где-то есть такая переменная, её можно использовать". Но вот это "где-то есть" тебе ещё надо обеспечить.

Comment: Тогда зачем я его экстерном в заголовочном объявлял?

Comment: @МатвейСуслов, дополнил.